# Ruby on Rails Hash#slice method returns empty hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, hash, slice, ruby-2.0, activesupport

Why does the first example return a hash with the two specified keys, while the second example returns an **empty** hash?

```
User.last.slice(:created_at, :updated_at)
=> {"created_at"=>Fri, 22 May 2015 00:33:37 UTC +00:00, "updated_at"=>Fri, 22 May 2015 01:00:06 UTC +00:00}

User.last.attributes.slice(:created_at, :updated_at)
=> {}
```

Notice the the difference in the examples is the use of `.attributes`, which returns a `Hash`.

```
User.last.attributes.class
=> Hash
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried something try(Attributes keys are string not symbols)

```
User.last.attributes.slice("created_at", "updated_at")
```

Comment: Your'e correct! I had found the solution and was going to write it myself if no one had answered.  I had gotten so used to Rails using `HashWithIndifferentAccess` in place of hashes.